# a joint defense agreement vs a defense agreement

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, usage

I only found the phrase "**a joint defense agreement**" that seems to relate to the forcing laws but I'm a foreigner and don't get it so well.
About the other, what is "**a defense agreement**" though? Give me expressions as much as possible please.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is about? Like what exactly are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

A joint defense agreement means a defense agreement between at least two allied parties, for example countries.

A defense agreement is a deal or a contract regarding military actions to protect the two allied parties, or collaborate on some military projects, like builiding a new fighter jet or a tank.